How do you get the text of a push notification with Appium/Wdio/iOS Simulator
I'm looking to get the text of a push notification text with Appium/Wdio JS on an iOS Simulator
I see there is a function for Android called openNotifications() but I have been searching for hours and can't find a solution for iOS.
I saw this as well but it doesn't seem to work:
await driver.execute('mobile: expectNotification', { name: 'AutomationTest' });


Any help is appreciated!

Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to open Notifications View on iOS. However, you still can do that as a regular user by swiping the whole screen from top to bottom. Depending on what Appium version you use.
Prior v.20.0.0 using the TouchActions:
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
PointOption startPoint = PointOption.point(size.width / 2, 1);
PointOption endPoint = PointOption.point(size.width / 2, size.height - 1);

new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions)driver)) 
    .press(startPoint) 
    .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(1L)))
    .moveTo(endPoint)
    .release()
    .perform();

After v.20.0.0:
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("mobile: swipe", 
        new Object[]{Map.of("direction", direction.getValue(), 
        "elementId", 
        ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId())});

Then, to get the notification message you need to use Appium Inspector and look for the respective locator. There could be several different strategies:

find all the notification cells using the driver.findElements(notificationCellLocator), get their text, and then assert that your resulting list contains the text you expected. Something like this:

List<String> notifications = driver.findElements(locator).stream()
    .map(WebElement::getText)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
assertThat(notifications)
    .as("There is no expected notification")
    .contains(expectedValue);


find the notification with the expected text value. In this case, you only need to assert the presence of the notification. Something like this:

var locator = String.format("label matches \".*%s.*\" and (name matches \".*%s.*\" or name = \"NotificationShortLookView\")", expectedText, extectedText);
var notification = driver.findElements(AppiumBy.iOSNsPredicateString(locator));

assertThat(notification.isDisplayed())
    .as("There is no expected notification")
    .isTrue();

You could also consider wrapping the code looking for the notification with retry.

Thank you! That gets me halfway there but I’ll need to assert on the notification for it to become beneficial for me. Is there a way to assert on the text of the notification?

@awhisler, I've added some details regarding the notification text assertions

Thanks! That looks like Java. I'm asking about WDIO which is JS, but Im sure I can figure it out
